# How can i run Elemento work fine in apache web server?

Tags: wordpress, apache, elementor

I tested on several servers, but the Elementor editor does not load
I download WordPress from the main site and install it
I install Elementor from the WordPress repository
But the element editor is not loaded

My old server is LiteSpeed and elementor work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
== Server Environment ==
    Operating System: Linux
    Software: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
    MySQL version: (Ubuntu) v8.0.33
    PHP Version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.13
    PHP Memory Limit: 128M
    PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
    PHP Max Post Size: 50M
    GD Installed: Yes
    ZIP Installed: Yes
    Write Permissions: All right
    Elementor Library: Connected

== WordPress Environment ==
    Version: 6.2.2
    Site URL: http://******.com
    Home URL: http://******.com
    WP Multisite: No
    Max Upload Size: 50 MB
    Memory limit: 40M
    Max Memory limit: 256M
    Permalink Structure: Plain
    Language: en-US
    Timezone: 0
    Admin Email: ******@gmail.com
    Debug Mode: Inactive

== Theme ==
    Name: Twenty Twenty-Three
    Version: 1.0
    Author: the WordPress team
    Child Theme: No

== User ==
    Role: administrator
    WP Profile lang: en_US
    User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

== Active Plugins ==
    Elementor
        Version: 3.14.1
        Author: Elementor.com


== Elementor Experiments ==
    Optimized DOM Output: Active by default
    Improved Asset Loading: Active by default
    Improved CSS Loading: Active by default
    Inline Font Icons: Inactive by default
    Accessibility Improvements: Active
    Additional Custom Breakpoints: Active by default
    admin_menu_rearrangement: Inactive by default
    Flexbox Container: Inactive by default
    Upgrade Swiper Library: Active by default
    Grid Container: Inactive by default
    Editor Top Bar: Inactive by default
    Landing Pages: Active by default
    Nested Elements: Inactive by default
    Nested Accordion: Inactive by default
    Lazy Load Background Images: Inactive by default
    Global Style Guide: Inactive by default


== Log ==
    
PHP: showing 1 of 1PHP: 2023-07-14 12:22:17 [notice X 1][/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/upgrade/manager.php::63] version_compare(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($version1) of type string is deprecated [array (
  'trace' => '
#0: Elementor\Core\Logger\Manager -> shutdown()
',
)]

Log: showing 5 of 52023-07-14 12:47:06 [info] Elementor data updater process has been queued. [array (
  'plugin' => 'Elementor',
  'from' => '3.14.1',
  'to' => '3.15.0-dev2',
)]
2023-07-14 12:47:16 [info] elementor::elementor_updater Started 
2023-07-14 12:47:16 [info] Elementor/Upgrades - _on_each_version Start  
2023-07-14 12:47:16 [info] Elementor/Upgrades - _on_each_version Finished 
2023-07-14 12:47:16 [info] Elementor data updater process has been completed. [array (
  'plugin' => 'Elementor',
  'from' => '3.14.1',
  'to' => '3.15.0-dev2',
)]



== Elementor - Compatibility Tag ==
```

Comment: It appears that this is intended to be additional details for your question, but you posted it as though it is an answer. Please edit this information into your question instead. Right now, it looks as though you’ve answered your own question and, thus, don’t require any further help.